# How can I assign a custom color to a cell in Aspose Cells?

Tags: excel-interop, aspose, aspose-cells, argb, colortransform

In the legacy (Excel Interop) code, this can be done to assign a custom color to a cell:

```
contractCell.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.FromArgb(202, 134, 250));
```

Using Aspose Cells, I'm trying to find the corresponding way to do it. This code:

```
styleContractRow2.ForegroundColor = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.FromArgb(202, 134, 250));
styleContractRow2.Pattern = BackgroundType.Solid;
```

...does not compile, telling me, "*Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Drawing.Color'*"

So how can I assign a custom color in Aspose Cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the reply and sample code in [your Aspose.Cells forum thread](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/822770/822806/showthread.aspx#822806).

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if the translation is unnecessary; this compiles:

```
styleContractRow2.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(202, 134, 250);
```